# Should I refrigerate solder paste?

Tags: soldering, solder-paste

I have a syringe of solder paste that is leaded, no clean.

I've had it a while and don't use it very often.  But I usually keep it in the refrigerator.  Is that necessary? Or, can I just leave it my utility drawer with everything else?

Thanks.

Comment: Typically solder paste gets used up before it gets old (e.g. in industry this is never a problem).  Just buy it in smaller volumes and then you don't have to refrigerate it.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping solder paste refrigerated will maintain the viscosity of the carrier and prevent the spheres of solder from settling to the bottom of the container. So, yes.

Comment: Does that mean I should flip the container over from time to time?  Especially if it sits in there for months without use?

Comment: Give it a good stir every couple of months or so.

Comment: It's in a syringe.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I have never refrigerated my solder paste and have never had any problems. Just keep it out of direct sunlight.

I have been soldering 0.5mm pitch QFNs and 0402 passives for years.

EDIT: Also, I don't advise putting solder paste in a fridge with items that will be consumed.

Comment: I keep it in a sealed container that is on a plastic shelf with sides so nothing can leak.  AND, the refrigerator I use is a small one that only contain sodas (and beer) and there is no way it could drip onto anything.  But, I appreciate the tip.  :-)